# Is it okay to grow English ivy on the base of a tree trunk?

Tags: trees, plant-health, english-ivy

In one place in the yard, there is a carpet of ivy under a black walnut. Would it harm the tree in any way to let the ivy up to the base of the branches? I would like to do this so that the whole scene is green.

Comment: Remember that English Ivy is considered an invasive pest in large parts of the US - including, I believe PA.

Comment: Okay so PA hasn't listed it as such, but a number of states with similar climates consider it to be an invasive. I would still be wary - just because it isn't a problem already doesn't mean you should help make it a problem!

Comment: It doesn't do well on its own here. It needs weeding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, as long as it doesn't compete for light, the tree is healthy, and the soil situation is normal, ivy is fine on tree *trunks*.  Ivy is not a parasite.  Here's a [good article](http://www.arborecology.co.uk/article_forf.htm).

The Alien Plant Working Group of the [Plant Conservation Alliance](http://www.nps.gov/plants/intro.htm)  lists [English Ivy as invasive](http://www.nps.gov/plants/alien/fact/hehe1.htm) in many states, including PA.

Answer (score 4):

Walnut and butternut trees try to ensure that there are no competitors for light and water by excreting a substance called juglone.  It inhibits the growth of [some plants](http://www.connon.ca/pdf_files/specsheets/Juglone%20Tolerant%20Plants.pdf).  I cannot find ivy listed as being tolerant which would indicate that it's growth would be stunted.

You could try [Virginia Creeper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenocissus_quinquefolia)  which is tolerant however a well established plant could compete with the walnut tree and inhibit it's growth.

With the [price of black walnut wood](http://ohioline.osu.edu/for-fact/0044.html) you could be better off pruning it so it has a good form and then selling it when you want to retire.

Comment: I would vote "no" to Virginia Creeper, it can be VERY invasive and is hard to get rid of.

Comment: I agree that Virginia Creeper gets out of control easily. However it is native and in the shade of a mature tree could be manageable.

Comment: Virginia creeper is a weed around here. The Ivy is already growing under the tree, so I don't think it will be a problem.